# I am trying to list all guild members with python requests but I am getting an error: {'message': 'Missing Access', 'code': 50001}

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I'm trying to get user list from my guild using python requests but I'm getting an error. I was able to read and send messages with this usage of auth token and api so I'm confused.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import hide

header = {
    'authorization': hide.authorization
}

url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{}/members'

_data = requests.get(url.format(hide.guild_id),headers=header)
data = _data.json()
print(_data)
print(data)
```

My output

```
<Response [403]>
{'message': 'Missing Access', 'code': 50001}
```

Comment: What's `hide` library? What value does `hide.authorization` have? For example if you insert a print statement what does it print?

Comment: hide.authorization holds my token in hide.py

Comment: maybe you don't have privileges for this. Maybe it needs to change some settings on discord server

Comment: Can you paste the output of `print(type(hide.authorization ))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response code 403 [means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403):

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server
> understands the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to 401, but for the 403 Forbidden status code
> re-authenticating makes no difference. The access is permanently
> forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient
> rights to a resource.

You probably haven't inserted the expected header name or header value. Probably the value.

To test it check the output of:

```
print(hide.authorization)
```